# Problem with View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, androidx

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.test.apptest.Home.HomePageActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(HomePageActivity.java:366)
```

The line 366 was:

```
ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon);
```

Apparently I am trying to use an object reference that has a null value.
I'm trying to understand where the problem, here I share part of the snippet:

**HomePageActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    Drawable drawable = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getIcon();
    if (drawable != null) {
        drawable.mutate();
        drawable.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(sharedObjects.getPrimaryColor()), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
    ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon); // <-- Here is the error
    searchIcon.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(sharedObjects.getPrimaryColor()));

    ImageView searchClose = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
    searchClose.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(sharedObjects.getPrimaryColor()));
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    searchEditText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    searchEditText.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor(sharedObjects.getFooterColor()));

   searchEditText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(sharedObjects.getPrimaryColor()));
    searchEditText.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(sharedObjects.getPrimaryColor()));
    searchEditText.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor(sharedObjects.getPrimaryColor())));
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Log.e("Submit", query);

            (menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)).collapseActionView();
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomePageActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEYWORD, query);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Log.e("TextChange", newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is the full code:

**activity_homepage.xml**: https://www.codepile.net/pile/X5yWyp18

**HomePageactivity.java**: https://www.codepile.net/pile/oJyYQWJK

Any help will be greatly appreciated, I have been investigating all afternoon

Comment: That would mean that `myActionMenuItem.getActionView()` is returning null, which means that the action `View`/layout for the `action_search` item in the `home` menu hasn't been set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Check first, if `myActionMenuItem.getActionView()` return null or not.

if `myActionMenuItem.getActionView()` is not null then try to replace your findViewById of `searchIcon` with this

```
ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace it is evident that the object `searchView` on which you are trying to invoke the method `findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon)` is null. So, inorder to fix this error :

- Add a null check on objects that are used as Java is not Null safe.
- Identify the code which creates the instance object for `SearchView` and why it is being set as `null`.

Please share the entire code so that we could make an informed decision on the solution.

Comment: Hello @Ananthapadmanabhan I have modified the answer to share the complete code.